# how can i fit four background images into one div

Tags: background-image

Am trying to fit four different background image in one grid div but is leaving a big gap in between the four corners and cant cover the whole area

```
grid-item3{
    background-image: url(./images/bg-section-top-desktop-1.svg),url(./images/bg-section-top-desktop-2.svg),url(./images/bg-section-bottom-desktop-1.svg),url(./images/bg-section-bottom-desktop-2.svg);
    background-position:left top,right top, left bottom, right bottom;
    background-size: contain,contain,contain,contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat,no-repeat,no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `background-size: cover, cover, cover, cover` ?

Comment: I did try:  background-size: cover, cover, cover, cover;   but it merge all the four images thereby destroying the shapes which i want at the four corners

Comment: Is there a codepen for this project? Can't guide you without some code.. especially when it involves CSS